# Connect to MySQL via PowerShell remote connect

Tags: mysql, powershell

When I use PowerShell to remote connect (Enter-PSSession) to a system, mysql.exe will not work. When I run this command `mysql.exe -u username -p password` nothing happens, the command prompt just blinks. When I use powershell on the system localy the same command works.

Answer (score 0):

Interactive command line executables are not supported in PowerShell Remoting.